# Update pivot table in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update a table with spots. I wanted to do it on click with livewire but nothing worked so I figured it would be easier to just use the methods in the Laravel controller that I already had. The attach and detach are used because I have two tables in my view, one with all the stations and the other one, the one I am trying to update, with the stations that are already in a workbook. With the way I have my method right now I can update everything except for the spot and I am not sure why. It is a many to many relationship between the workbooks and stations and spots are an extra field in the pivot table.

```
 <form action="{{route('admin.workbooks.update', [$client_id, $workbook_id])}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
          @method('PUT')

            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Media Schedule Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="wrkb_name" value="{{$workbook_name}}">
            </div>
            <table class="table-auto w-full mb-6">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="px-4 py-2"></th>
                @if($showLetter)
              <th wire:click="sortBy('call_letter')" style="cursor: pointer;" class="px-4 py-2">Call Letter @include('partials.sort-icon',['field'=>'call_letter'])</th>
              @endif           
              <th  style="cursor: pointer;" class="px-4 py-2">Spots @include('partials.sort-icon',['field'=>'spots'])</th>
              
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($selected_stations as $key => $selected_station)

              <tr>
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                    <input  name="selected_stations[]" wire:model="selected_already" value="{{ $selected_station->id }}" type="checkbox">
                </td>
              
                @if($showLetter)
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{$selected_station->call_letter}}</td>
                @endif
                
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                    <input name="spot" type="text" class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" value="{{$selected_station->pivot->spot}}" placeholder="{{$selected_station->pivot->spot}}"></td>
                <td>
              </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
<br>
        <table class="table-auto w-full mb-6">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="px-4 py-2"></th>
              
                @if($showLetter)
              <th wire:click="sortBy('call_letter')" style="cursor: pointer;" class="px-4 py-2">Call Letter @include('partials.sort-icon',['field'=>'call_letter'])</th>
              @endif
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($stations as $key => $station)
              <tr>
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                    <input  name="stations[]" wire:model="selected" value="{{ $station->id }}" type="checkbox">
                </td>
                @if($showLetter)
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{$station->call_letter}}</td>
                @endif
               
                <td>
              </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
    
        @else
            <p class="text-center">Whoops! No users were found </p>
        @endif
        <div class="w-full flex pb-10" >
            <div class="w-1/6 relative mx-1 space-x-6">
                <button class="block appearance-none w-full bg-black border border-gray-200 text-white py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500">Edit Media Schedule</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

```
    public function update(UpdateWorkbookRequest $request,Client $client, Workbook $workbook)
    {
        $workbook->update($request->only('wrkb_name'));
        $workbook->stations()->detach($request->input('selected_stations', []));
        $workbook->stations()->attach($request->input('stations', []));
        $workbook->stations()->updateExistingPivot('spot', []);
        return redirect()->route('admin.workbooks.edit', [$client->id, $workbook->id])->with('success', 'Successfully Edited the Workbook');
    
    }
```

This is how one of the relationship looks like, although I don't think this helps much

```
    public function workbooks()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Workbook::class, 'station_workbook', 'station_id', 'workbook_id')->withPivot('spot')->withTimestamps();;
    }
```

I also found that I could use something like this, but I only want to update that specific record and from this code it seems like it updates every instance of that station, no matter what workbook and it doesn't work anyway.

```
        foreach($workbook->stations as $key => $station){
            dd($station->workbooks);
            $station->workbooks()->updateExistingPivot($key, ['spot' => $request ->spot]);
        }
```

I have also tried this with no success

```
        $usedStations=$request->input('stations', []);

        $workbook->update($request->only('wrkb_name'));
        $workbook->stations()->detach($request->input('selected_stations', []));
        $workbook->stations()->attach($request->input('stations', []));
        foreach($usedStations as $usedStation)
        {
            $station_id = Station::where('id',$usedStation)->value('id');
            $workbook->stations()->updateExistingPivot($station_id, ['spot' => $request ->spot]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from Laravel Doc: ([Link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships))

> When attaching a relationship to a model, you may also pass an array
> of additional data to be inserted into the intermediate table

So, you can do :

```
$workbook->stations()->attach($request->input('stations', []),['spot'=>$request->input('spot')]);
```

**UPDATE**

Currently, in your code only single value for 'spot' field is being passed to the request. Change it to:

```
<input name="spot[{{$selected_station->id}}]" type="text" class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" value="{{$selected_station->pivot->spot}}" placeholder="{{$selected_station->pivot->spot}}"></td>
```

update() method should be:

```
        public function update(UpdateWorkbookRequest $request,Client $client, Workbook $workbook)
            {
                $workbook->update($request->only('wrkb_name'));
                $workbook->stations()->detach($request->input('selected_stations', []));
                $workbook->stations()->attach($request->input('stations', []));
//take only the spot values of selected_stations that were unchecked
                $spots = array_diff_key($request->input('spot',[]), array_flip($request->input('selected_stations',[])));

                foreach($spots as $station_id=>$spot_value){
                            $workbook->stations()->updateExistingPivot($station_id, ['spot'=>$spot_value]);
    
    }
                return redirect()->route('admin.workbooks.edit', [$client->id, $workbook->id])->with('success', 'Successfully Edited the Workbook');
            
            }
```

Comment: That is something that I overlooked. Although in my case it would be an update on the stations that are already included in the workbook. My attach and detach requests are used only to bring in or discard certain stations from a workbook so I would need it separate from the attachment of a station

Comment: Can you please post the full code of your form? It would help to understand your problem better.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. From your form code what I understand that you have a list of checkboxes for previously selected stations along with a "spot" text box and another list of checkboxes having all the stations. What you are trying to achieve is "checked" selected stations will be removed and "checked" stations from all stations list will be added instead for that specific workbook. You also want to update the spot value for "unchecked" selected stations. Did I understand your intention cottectly?

Comment: Yes and everything works except for the update of the spots. I also tried to do it in Livewire but with no luck

Comment: Will the value of "spot" field be different for each selected station? In your current code only one value is being passed, not separate value for seperate station. Is it supposed to be the intended behaviour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235361/discussion-between-alexandra-claudia-and-zihad).

Comment: @AlexandraClaudia I have updated my answer based on your feedback. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: with this little twitch it works perfectly. Please update your comment too so that others can use it. Thank you so much! $spots = array_diff_key($request->input('spot',[]), array_flip($request->input('selected_stations', [])));

Comment: Attempt to read property "spot" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\SFM\resources\views\livewire\edit-workbooks-table.blade.php) Do you have any idea why this would appear? It is related to this part of the code $selected_station->pivot->spot

Comment: Solved it with a bit of livewire. I changed it to $current_workbook->stations()->find($selected_station->id)->pivot->spot where in mount I initialize $this->current_workbook = Workbook::find($this->workbook_id);

Comment: I am glad everything worked out for you in the end.